# ASP.NET membership redirect to a page by user role

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

I have 3 roles which are Manager, Employee and Accountant. I'm using asp.net membership. When all users in those roles logged in, they go to Default.aspx. How can redirect them by checking their roles? I.e When user logged in with Manager role, he should go to Manager.aspx. And those users which logged in can type Login.aspx and they see it. They shouldn't see it when they logged in. How can I handle those problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method

```
Roles.IsUserInRole( String roleName )
```

should do what you're looking for.

As in:

```
if ( Roles.IsUserInRole( "Manager" ) )
{
    Response.Redirect( "~/ManagerLandingPage.aspx" );
}
```

Comment: I couldn't type Roles.IsUserInRole because I didnt handle login by my hand. asp.net membership did itself. Where should I write it?

Comment: @AnılCanlı how are you doing roles?

Comment: @Anil - I'm not sure what you're asking here. You should be able to put this in your code-behind. You will need to include the appropriate assembly by having `using System.Web.Security` at the top of your module.

Comment: I'm doing by Web Administrator Tool. By adding roles and adding users in those roles

Answer (score 4):

Something like:

```
if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Manager")
{
    Response.Redirect("~/ManagerPage.aspx");
}
```